# Protecting iframe src using server side rendering

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, api, iframe

I have to display a third party site, say site X, upon successful authentication from my existing APIs, as it is, on my web site. But due to certain reasons, I cannot afford to use an iframe, which is the most obvious solution in this case, as that will expose the site X's URL when inspected in browser. So, I landed up on another idea to create a web app whose front end is written in AngularJS and use existing back end APIs written in C#. The application will basically have two pages, login and main page. Upon successful authentication from API on login page, user is navigated to main page. Now main page, I have to show another site. So, instead of using iframe on main page having source as site X, I will display an iframe with source Url as one of my API endpoint, say baseURL/data. So, this API will basically fetch the site X data and do something like server side rendering and return me an exact replica of site X which I will load in my webapp. When user will navigate on site X and route to any path, that route will be sent to same API and now the response will be replica of baseURL/data/route. Even though my API endpoint is now exposed instead of site X url in browser console, I am okay with this because that API is protected somehow and cannot be accessed as it is without proper authentication which I am doing in my case on login page.

I want to get more thoughts on this entire scenario and possible alternatives. Also, if anyone can suggest if/how it is possible to write such an API. I can think about changing AngularJS or C# as technologies in my project but definitely that's not the most go-to-solution for me. Any suggestions and thoughts are welcome!

Edit: I have created a site using a static site generator. I want my users to be able to access that site only if they are 'my users' i.e. authenticated by my APIs. But, that generator is not allowing me to integrate my API and neither I can get the static assets like .html, .css and .js files that I can host on my own server and integrate my authentication API. Hence, I had to think about a workaround like this.

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to show the "live" version of the site, scraping it and displaying it in an iframe like this is the only way. But you're going to run into a lot of problems if the source site has many dependencies (stylesheets, scripts, etc). Can I ask why you need to protect the source site, and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin, I have edited my question to include the details that you need. Kindly consider those and provide some solution. Thanks.